# chef user resource does not update an existing user's home directory if it already exists

Tags: linux, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Im trying to make sure my chef recipe creates a new unix user or alters the existing user if it already exists ,using the following resource

```
 user 'postgres' do
   supports :manage_home => true
   home '/home/postgres'
   shell '/bin/bash'    
   password #{password}
   action :create
 end
```

But inthe following case:
user postgres is already created but owner of /home/postgres is root
The recipe gives output  `user[postgres] action create (up to date)`
even though `:manage_home => true` is specified.
Is there better way to create/update a user and its home directory ?

Comment: From what I can see [in the code](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/d75f48cda2839e96d2ee1de81aa9e08fddeae623/lib/chef/provider/user/useradd.rb#L118-L120), Chef is calling only `usermod -d #{home} -m`, which moves the home directory to `home`. If the directory already exists, `usermod` does probably nothing. So where did you create the home dir with `root` ownership - or can you find out, when it is created?

Comment: It was created at the same location (/home/postgres). So i'm guessing chef will not update the owner and group of the existing to postgres ?

Comment: Did you create it manually as root? As said, chef doesn't deal with the ownerships there. I expect that it creates it correctly (through the  `useradd` command), but it doesn't care about ownerships itself.

Comment: So in this case(ie. i already have a user named postgres on the chef node but his home dir is owned by root) if i am to correctly create a new user with a user managed home dir using chef..it would be better to explicitly remove the old user and the user home dir before running that user resource right ? ...or is there a better way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the only thing `:manage_home => true` does is creating the home directory if it does not exist. If it exists it does nothing, even if there are wrong permissions.

I have a directory resource coming after every user resource, that makes sure home folder is correct:

```
directory '/home/postgres' do
  owner 'postgres'
  group 'postgres'
  mode 0755
end
```